# CompletableFuture | thenApplyAsync vs thenCompose and their use cases

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I was trying to understand CompletableFuture, and came across 2 methods, thenApplyAsync and thenCompose.
Am trying to understand the difference between these two.

```
CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Printing hello");
    return "Hello";
}).thenCompose((String s) -> {
  return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Adding abc");
      return "abc "+s;});
}).thenApplyAsync((String s) -> {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Adding world");
    return s + " World";
}).thenApplyAsync((String s) -> {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Adding name");
    if (false) {
       throw new RuntimeException("Oh no exception");
    }
    return s + " player!";
}).handle((String s, Throwable t) -> {
    System.out.println(s != null ? s : "BLANK");
    System.out.println(t != null ? t.getMessage() : "BLANK Exception");
    return s != null ? s : t.getMessage();
});
```

How I interpreted these methods as, `thenApplyAsync` will execute the supplied function in a different thread and return a result, but internally it is wrapped inside a CompletionStage. Whereas, `thenCompose` will get the return a reference to a CompletionStage.

So under what scenarios, will I use `thenCompose` over `thenApplyAsync`?

Went through this link, but it was talking about `thenApply`, which is somewhat different:
[CompletableFuture | thenApply vs thenCompose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019126/completablefuture-thenapply-vs-thencompose)

Comment: There's very little difference between `thenApply` and `thenApplyAsync`, so the linked question should answer you quite well.

Comment: It seems you are assuming that the only thing you could do in the function passed to `thenCompose`, is to call `supplyAsync` so that the net result is similar to `thenApplyAsync`. Consider that you could do entirely different things in the function passed to `thenCompose` instead…

Comment: @JoeC he linked that question in his question. Plus this question is "thenApplyAsync vs thenCompose" different things

Comment: Fundamentally, the answer is the same.  The `thenCompose` method is really meant for APIs which return `CompletableFuture`s, whereas `thenApplyAsync` is meant for those which don't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would use `thenCompose` when you have an operation that returns a `CompletionStage` and `thenApply` when you have an operation that doesn't return a `CompletionStage`. -> This is was is in [thenApply vs thenCompose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019126/completablefuture-thenapply-vs-thencompose)

However the `Async` variants of the `CompletionStage` interface have subtle difference and rare use cases.

Let's take this example into account:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class Futures {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        CompletableFuture<Void> c = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {

            System.out.println("run1: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        });

        c.whenComplete((r, t) -> {
            System.out.println("I'm completed");
        });

        c.thenCompose(__ -> {
            System.out.println("thenCompose1: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                System.out.println("run2: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            });
        }).thenRunAsync(() -> {
            System.out.println("RunAsync1: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        });

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        System.out.println("Finished");
    }
}
```

Which outputs something like:

```
run1: 11
thenCompose1: 11
run2: 12
I'm completed
RunAsync1: 11
Finished
```

Notice that `thenApplyAsync` doesn't not affect the original future's completed state in contrast with the non async variants which do affect the completed state of the `CompletionStage`.

### Use cases:

#### `thenCompose`

You might `thenCompose` when you have 2 asynchronous operations that need to be executed sequentially:

```
static CompletionStage<String> insert(Object database) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

static CompletionStage<Object> get(String id) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Object db = new Object(); // pretend this connects to a database
    CompletionStage<Object> recordInserted = insert(db).thenCompose(id -> get(id));
}
```

You can only retrieve the record after you inserted it.

#### `Async` variants of `thenXXXX` methods

Imagine for a moment that you have an application that allows users to register themselves and upon registration they will receive a confirmation email to confirm their account.

You don't want the user to be waiting for ever if the mail server is down or if it takes a long time to compose the email or perform additional checks.

You would then use `thenApplyAsync` to fire off the send email logic because it is not crucial to your system. A user can always go back and say "send me another email"

```
static CompletionStage<String> register(String username) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

static void sendConfirmationEmail(String username) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    register("user").thenAcceptAsync(username -> sendConfirmationEmail(username));

}
```

Here your system will respond when the registration is complete but it will not wait for the email to be sent resulting in improved responsiveness of your system.

The uses cases I've found so far for the `Async` variants are scarce but they do exist.

Comment: Too late to comment on this. But I am not sure this is correct
 "**_`thenApply` when you have an operation that doesn't return a CompletionStage._**"
My understanding is `thenApply` also returns Completion Stage

Comment: It can, but then you'll end up with a `CompletionStage<CompletionStage<T>>`

Comment: got it. So it will be correct to say `thenApply` does return CompletionStage but it can be nested like `CompletionStage<CompletionStage<T>>` depending  on when thenApply has been called in the chain of CompletableFutures.

Comment: Yes, but you rarely want to have a nested `CompletionStage`

Comment: For me running your first piece of code is spawning 3 different threads. Also thenRunAsync should run on a new thread.
`run1: 10
thenCompose1: 10
I'm completed
run2: 11
RunAsync1: 12`

@pedromss