# Difference between Java8 thenCompose and thenComposeAsync

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

Given this piece of code:

```
public List<String> findPrices(String product){
    List<CompletableFuture<String>> priceFutures =
    shops.stream()
         .map(shop -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                () -> shop.getPrice(product), executor))
         .map(future -> future.thenApply(Quote::parse))
         .map(future -> future.thenCompose(quote ->
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                        () -> Discount.applyDiscount(quote), executor
                )))
         .collect(toList());

    return priceFutures.stream()
                       .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                       .collect(toList());
}
```

This part of it:

```
.map(future -> future.thenCompose(quote ->
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                        () -> Discount.applyDiscount(quote), executor
                )))
```

Could it be rewrite as:

```
.map(future -> 
    future.thenComposeAsync(quote -> Discount.applyDiscount(quote), executor))
```

I took this code from an example of a book and says the two solutions are different, but I do not understand why.

Comment: I would advice you to read https://stackoverflow.com/a/46063193/1746118 the Async Variants part specifically to understand the difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's consider a function that looks like this:

```
public CompletableFuture<String> requestData(String parameters) {
    Request request = generateRequest(parameters);
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> sendRequest(request));
}
```

The difference will be with respect to which thread `generateRequest()` gets called on.

`thenCompose` will call `generateRequest()` on the same thread as the upstream task (or the calling thread if the upstream task has already completed).

`thenComposeAsync` will call `generateRequest()` on the provided executor if provided, or on the default `ForkJoinPool` otherwise.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46060438/1746118 in terms of the answer that the question would lead to?

Comment: I see where you're coming from, but I don't think there's enough of an overlap to really call it a duplicate.