# Passing a CompletableFuture's result to another

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future

I am relatively inexperienced with Java's CompletableFuture and I probably need some help with it. Here is what I am trying to do.

```
/* I want to use the result of the future in a second one.
 * So basically, what I want to do is to return the second future,
 * but I don't want to block and wait for the first future to complete.
 * /
CompletableFuture<TypeA> -> CompletableFuture<TypeB>
```

So I am wondering if there is a way to 'chain' the first future to the second one such that one single future(TypeB) will be returned.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why don't you pass the future object itself along?

Comment: `thenCompose` is the bind for the CompleatableFuture.

Answer (score 3):

The [`thenCompose`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCompose-java.util.function.Function-) method does exactly that.

Here is an example at https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture:

> ```
> CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture 
>   = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "Hello")
>     .thenCompose(s -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> s + " World"));
>
> assertEquals("Hello World", completableFuture.get());
> ```

Also have a look at the [difference between thenCompose and thenComposeAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46130969/difference-between-java8-thencompose-and-thencomposeasync).

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem when trying to write **test code** and the future that has to be tested is **created in a background thread** so we cannot simply chain it with the outer future that we want to use for asserting.

My colleague created the following method.

```
static <U> void propagateResultWhenCompleted(
    final CompletionStage<U> source,
    final CompletableFuture<U> target)
{
    source.whenComplete((r, t) -> complete(target, r, t));
}
```

*I wonder why this is not in the standard tool set. Surely it is not the idiomatic way of using futures but it is handy for some occasions.*