# How to use CompletableFuture to execute the threads parallaly without waiting and combine the result?

Tags: asynchronous, parallel-processing, java.util.concurrent, completable-future, java-threads

I have executeGetCapability method which is executed in different threads but these threads runs sequentially..meaning one is completed after the other

```
    @Async("threadPoolCapabilitiesExecutor")
    public CompletableFuture<CapabilityDTO>  executeGetCapability(final String id, final LoggingContextData data){...}
```

and this method is called in following way:

```
public CapabilityResponseDTO getCapabilities(final List<String> ids) {
    final CapabilityResponseDTO responseDTO = new CapabilityResponseDTO();
    final List<CapabilityDTO> listOfCapabilityDTOS = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        for (String id: ids) {
            listOfCapabilityDTOS .add(
                    asyncProcessService.executeGetCapability(id, LoggingContext.getLoggingContextData()).get());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ....
    }
    responseDTO.setDTOS(listOfCapabilityDTOS );
    return responseDTO;
}
```

How can i call executeGetCapability method using CompletableFuture so that thread runs in parallel without waiting for each other and then the result is combined ?? how can i use here `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` and or `.allOf` methods ? Can someone explain me

Thanks

Comment: You essentially want to convert a list of futures to a future for a list. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74452659/402428
And if you don't mind adding a thin wrapper around `CompletableFuture`, then have a look at my `BetterFuture` implementation, which supports this via its `reduce` method: https://github.com/mduerig/better-future

Answer (score 1):

The [reduce helper function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74452659/402428) from this answer converts a `CompletableFuture<Stream<T>>` to a `Stream<CompletableFuture<T>>`. You can use it to asynchronously combine the results for multiple calls to `executeGetCapability`:

```
// For each id create a future to asynchronously execute executeGetCapability
Stream<CompletableFuture<CapabilityDTO>> futures = ids.stream()
    .map(id -> executeGetCapability(id, LoggingContext.getLoggingContextData()));

// Reduce the stream of futures to a future for a stream 
// and convert the stream to list
CompletableFuture<List<CapabilityDTO>> capabilitiesFuture = reduce(futures)
    .thenApply(Stream::toList);

responseDTO.setDTOS(capabilitiesFuture.get());
```