# CompletableFuture with api call

Tags: java, parallel-processing, completable-future

I am trying to use CompletableFuture with lambda api call. I receive a set of inputs that I need to process via my lambda in batches of 5 and then display them. I am using CompletableFuture for the first time and want to understand if i am using it correctly to help parallel process my code. I want to call the api in paralleling for every 5 inputs.

```
List<Info> listOfInputs = new LinkedList<>();

List<CompletableFuture<List<Info>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    for (int iterator = 0; iterator < inputs.length; iterator = iterator + 5)) {
        int finalIterator = iterator;
        CompletableFuture<List<Info>> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            return getAllInputs(Arrays.copyOfRange(inputs, finalIterator,
                                    Math.min(inputs.length, finalIterator + 5)));
        });
        futures.add(future);
    }
    CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(
            futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
    allFutures.join();

    for (CompletableFuture<List<Info>> future : futures) {
        List<Info> info = future.get();
        for (int i = 0; i < info.size(); i++) {
            listOfInputs.add(info.get(i));
        }
    }

    listOfInputs.stream().map(infoEntry -> {
            sout("Hello" + infoEntry) });  
}
```

Comment: Yes this is basically how to do it when you want to rely on `CompletableFuture.allOf`. However, I prefer to do this as describe in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74662100/402428 Basically, write a helper function that can convert a `CompletableFuture<Stream<T>>` to a `Stream<CompletableFuture<T>>`.

Comment: I notice that getAllInputs input is called multiple times, but it waits for all the iterations to complete before doing futures.add(future). It looks like it is slowing my process, is there a better way to achieve parallel processing for my use case. Thank you.