# What is a case where `thenApply()` vs. `thenCompose()` is ambiguous despite the return type of the lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, language-design, completable-future

I'm learning about `CompletableFuture`s.

**I am not asking about [the difference between `thenApply()` and `thenCompose()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019126/completablefuture-thenapply-vs-thencompose).** Instead, I want to ask about a code "scent" that doesn't feel right, and what might actually justify it.

From the usages of `CompletableFuture`s I've seen so far, it seems you'd never have this:

```
CompletableFuture<String> foo = getSomething().thenApply((result) -> { ... });
```

Nor this:

```
String foo = getSomething().thenCompose((result) -> { ... });
```

To return a future, you have to use `thenCompose()`, and otherwise `thenApply()`.

From experience though, it seems weird that language didn't devise a way to eliminate making this unambiguous choice every time. For example, couldn't there have been a single method `thenDo()` whose return type is inferred (during compile-time) from the `return` within the lambda? It could then be given `thenApply` or `thenCompose`-like properties at compile-time as well.

But I'm sure there's a good reason for having separate methods, so I'd like to know why.

- Is it because it's dangerous or not possible to infer return types from lambdas in Java? (I'm new to Java as well.)
- Is it because there is a case in which a single method would indeed be ambiguous, and the only solution is to have separate methods? (I'm imagining maybe, nested `CompletableFuture`s or complicated interfaces and generics.) If so, can someone provide a clear example?
- Is it for some other reason or documented recommendation?

Comment: How could `thenDo()` replace those methods, when they are different? In your naming, they would be `thenDoNow()` vs. `thenDoInBackground()`. They are not the same.

Comment: "*Is it because it's dangerous or not possible to infer return types from lambdas in Java?*" - I wouldn't say that's the reason for distinguishing the two methods, but yes, that's a true statement. A lambda's type, including type parameters, is inferred from its context, not the other way around.

Comment: @Andreas - I guess thought the compiler should already _know_ whether `thenDoNow()` or `thenDoBackground()` based on what is being returned in the lambda...

Comment: @AndrewCheong On what's being *returned*? Don't you mean on what's being passed in? You're the one *telling* the method what *you* want it to do.

Comment: @Andreas - It seems I've completely misunderstood the methods. Thanks. Back to the basics for me... Voting to self-close.

Comment: The big problem is that the accepted answer of the linked question is not a good one. It reads like the purpose of `thenCompose` was what actually `thenApplyAsync` is for. The difference between `thenApply` and `thenCompose` is a fundamental one, deserving a different name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reference, the signatures of the two methods are:

```
<U> CompletableFuture<U>   thenApply(Function<? super T,? extends U> fn)
<U> CompletableFuture<U> thenCompose(Function<? super T,? extends CompletionStage<U>> fn)
```

`Function<? super T,? extends U>` and `Function<? super T,? extends CompletionStage<U>>` have `Function<? super T, ?>` as a common supertype (ok, technically it's just `Function`).

Therefore the signature of `thenDo` would be something like:

```
<U> CompletableFuture<U> thenDo(Function<? super T,?> fn)
```

which, while legal, would be a real pain to use as the compiler would have no way to check whether the return type for `fn` is correct and would have to accept anything.

Also, the implementation of this `thenDo` would have no other option but to `apply` the function and check whether the returned object `implements CompletionStage`, which (besides being slow and... repugnantly inelegant) would have real issues in non-straightforward cases: what would happen when calling `thenDo` on a `CompletableFuture<CompletionStage<String>>`?

---

If you are new to java generics, my recommendation is to concentrate on understanding two things first and foremost:

1. Covariance/contravariance of type parameters (or rather lack thereof). Why isn't `List<String>` a subtype of `List<Object>`? What's the difference between `List<Object>` and `List<?>`?
2. Type erasure. Why can't I overload a method based on a generic parameter?

After you have those set, investigate how type variables can be resolved via reflection (eg: understand how Guava's [`TypeToken`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html) works)

---

*edit:* fixed a link

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of the differences is wrong.  Both thenApply and thenCompose return CompletableFuture's (or, well, CompletionStages).

The difference between them is what you've hidden in the `(result) -> { ... }` part.

For `thenApply`, you want that function to return a `String` to make the whole line return a `CompleteableFuture<String>`.

For `thenCompose`, you want that function to return a `CompleteableFuture<String>` to make the whole line return a `CompleteableFuture<String>`.